# Retrieve in-app purchases with Android BillingClient 2.1, returns empty list

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm trying retrieve a list (just one item) of available purchases using the Android BillingClient 2.1 as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Query). Like this:

```
private suspend fun querySkuDetails() {
    val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
    skuList.add("premium_upgrade")
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
    val skuDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        billingClient.querySkuDetails(params.build())
    }
    if (skuDetailsResult.billingResult.responseCode ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsResult.skuDetailsList != null) {
        for (skuDetails in skuDetailsResult.skuDetailsList as List<SkuDetails>) {
            val sku = skuDetails.sku
            val price = skuDetails.price
            if ("premium_upgrade" == sku) {
                premiumUpgradePrice = price
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the play store console I have uploaded the app prepared the store page and added a managed product called "premium_upgrade". But I have not yet published the app, as its missing this vital part.

For some reason `skuDetailsResult.skuDetailsList` is always returned empty. There is no `debugMessage` in `billingResult`. So I'm a bit stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found the testing part further down in the left hand menu. 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing

When testing locally I had to change the sku product id to one of of the reserved google ids. So for testing I had to change `premium_upgrade` to `android.test.purchased` then you can try the entire flow.

Once you have made a test purchase of a manage product it will say that you already own the product and you get kind of blocked there. If you need to re-test the purchase you can use this adb command the clear the purchase history and run it again.

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```